# section class not displaying image using sass

Tags: html, css, sass

Hello I can't get a hero background image in my section class is sass

HTML & SASS

```css
.hero
  background: url("heroimage.jpg")
  min-height: 100%
  background-size: cover
  background-position: 50% 0
```

```html
  <section class="hero">
    <div class="container grid">
      <div class="hero-text col">
        <h1 class="title-large">Hi I'm <span>Jamie Wales</span></h1>
          <p class="text-intro">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
            aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
            reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
            fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
          <a href="" class'btn btn--secondary'>Learn More</a>
          <a href="" class'btn btn--primary'>Get In Touch!</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <img src="img/mainlogo.png" alt="" class="hero-img">
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Background color works but not Background image, am I missing something? Any help and I would be very greatful

Answer (score 1):

First of all check that your image exists in the root directory that the code file is in as you are not defining it's location.

second give the class a width.

You can see my working example here (JSFiddle)

```
.hero {
     background: url('https://media.giphy.com/media/vvZeaCj5tf0qY/giphy.gif');
     min-height: 100%;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: 50% 0;
     width:100%;
}
```

The only things i changed was

an absolute link image.
List item added a width..